# Sql auto input the columns that i concated

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have columns Fname and Lname and Full Name.

I want to create a function that when I input Fname and Lname it appear in column Full Name.

[image]

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `inser_customer`(Cname VARCHAR(50), CMname VARCHAR(50),CLname VARCHAR(50), edad VARCHAR(50), sex VARCHAR(50), brgay VARCHAR(50), sity VARCHAR(50), Cno VARCHAR(50), gmail VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
SET @full=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Fname,' ', Lname) FROM customer);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Fname = Cname AND Lname = CLname)THEN
RETURN "Customer Already Exists";
ELSE INSERT INTO customer (`Fname`,`Mname`,`Lname`,`Birthdate`,`Gender`,`Brgy`,`City`,`ContactNo`,`Email`,`Full Name`)VALUES(Cname, CMname, CLname, edad, sex, brgay, sity, Cno, gmail, @full2);
RETURN "OK";
END IF;
    END$$
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want that after `INSERT`, after `UPDATE`, both?

Comment: @Wistar after INSERT

Comment: @Wistar Your a life saver..

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer satisfies you, you can also up vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Trigger` for that.

[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

> A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. Some uses for triggers are to perform checks of values to be inserted into a table or to perform calculations on values involved in an update.

After you insert a new row

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER full_name_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.`Full Name` = CONCAT(NEW.`Fname`, " ",NEW.`Lname`)
END;//
delimiter ;
```

I suggest you had a trigger after you update an existing row for better consistency and maintenance

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER full_name_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.`Full Name` = CONCAT(NEW.`Fname`, " ",NEW.`Lname`)
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you try a unit-test like function first like so and then adapt it to your needs:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `firstname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Then create the function:

```
delimiter //

create function insert_test_data (
  mFirstname varchar(20),
  mLastname varchar(20)
)
returns varchar(50)
begin
  set @fullname = trim( concat( trim(mFirstname), ' ', trim(mLastname) ) );

  if exists (
    select 1 from test
    where firstname = mFirstname
          and lastname = mLastname
  ) then
    return 'Customer already exists';
  else
    insert into test (firstname, lastname, fullname) values
    (mFirstname, mLastname, @full);
    return 'OK';
  end if;

end //

delimiter ;
```

To insert data:

```
select insert_test_data ('john', 'smith');
+------------------------------------+
| insert_test_data ('john', 'smith') |
+------------------------------------+
| OK                                 |
+------------------------------------+

select * from test;
+-----------+----------+----------+
| firstname | lastname | fullname |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| john      | smith    | NULL     |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

If the customer already exists, you'll get this:

```
select insert_test_data ('john', 'smith');
+------------------------------------+
| insert_test_data ('john', 'smith') |
+------------------------------------+
| Customer already exists            |
+------------------------------------+
```

Recommendation:

I recommend that you NOT add a calculated field. You could just enter firstname and lastname. When it comes to extracting data, just do this:

```
select trim( concat( trim(firstname), ' ', trim(lastname) ) )
from test;
```

So you can work with this information on the fly.